# How make a wait import sql file?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, kubernetes-health-check

I have 3 containers: `nginx`, `php-fpm` and `mysql 5.7` . I import a large SQL file with volume. When I connect to the container `mysql`, see only part of the tables.

How to properly wait for SQL file import. Could give an example of use (healthcheck or .sh file)?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ , and you need to use the init feature form mysql docker using vlolumes

Answer (score 1):

Well there is this pipe viewer which you can use to import from dump files. It nicely explained inside this [DBA case](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/how-can-i-monitor-the-progress-of-an-import-of-a-large-sql-file).

You can use [livenessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) to check if mysql is responding, this might look like the following:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command: ["mysqladmin", "ping"]
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```

It waits 30 second before first check, after that each 10 seconds there is another check. Timeout for failure is set to 5 seconds.

You can also use [readinessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) which is used to check if database is ready for accepting connections:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
     # Check we can execute queries over TCP (skip-networking is off).
    command: ["mysql", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "-e", "SELECT 1"]
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 2
  timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Command will be executed after 5 seconds from container start and it will be executed each 2 seconds. Probe will fail after 1 second of timeout. The `pod` won't be in `Ready` state so it won't accept connections if the probe is failing.